# Limitation in Number of Win Forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I am writing WinForms application, and so far it contains 37 forms. This is because of my project's needs.

My questions are:

1. Is there a limitation to the number of forms created in C#?
2. Does it have an effect on application performance?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a limitation in forms creation in C# ?

AFAIK there is no such limitation imposed by the the .NET Framework. Obviously the more forms you create and keep in memory, the less memory you will have until you run out of it. And the less memory you have could lead to slower performance.

On the other hand if you keep in memory only the current form and leave the GC take care of the others by leaving their instances fall out of scope there won't be such problems.

Comment: so in this situation , will i have a problem including memory , ... ?

Comment: @Real2000, in which situation? If you keep all the forms in memory?

Comment: as your idea what is the best way to implement this work ? is it better to use TabControl instead of using multi forms ?

Comment: is this that i have 37 created !?

Comment: @Real2000, if you use a TabControl with many controls and *pseudo forms*, this would mean that all of them are loaded in memory at the same time which depending on the volume might not be very good.

Comment: you are true,i mean is there a maximum level of form creating for not having memory problems ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit on number of forms until you run out of ram. It will affect both system and application performance though.

Comment: I agree. It might be, however, that using that many forms might trigger bug symptoms in VS you would never see with one or two forms.

Comment: @ TheBlastOne : so what is solution in which we need more forms ?!

Answer (score 0):

not that I know of, or other modules or classes within a project can create as many you'll need without any restrictions.

Regards.

Comment: but on the other side we will have memory loss !

Comment: Hello, sorry for my bad English because then I realized-level designers, but if you intend to open several at runtime, then I agree with you, when there will be more free memory you have an error in OutOfMemory exception.Regards

Comment: you mean with large number of forms (i.e up to 50) if we don't open many forms at a time,we won't have memory problems ?

Answer (score 0):

I had an project with too many winforms in it(Approx 50). After 2 or 3 Debug Builds and Runs i used to get following error.

> ```
> Error 1   Unexpected error writing metadata to file
> ```
>
> 'E:\Repository\Project\JewelSoft\PresentationTier\obj\Release\PresentationTier.exe'
>   -- 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
>   ' PresentationTier

So take care and always implement GC where ever required.

**Update 1:**
Although there are methods like GC.Collect(), you dont often require to implement it unless you have cases that your code ends abruptly or switches the threads. Things like Disposing the forms which are not required after closing and avoiding repetitive declarations of object will be helpful.

**Update 2:**
To know more when are where to write GC.Collect please refer these links:

1. [GC.Collect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149197/gc-collect)
2. [When to call GC.Collect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx)
3. [When is it acceptable to call GC.Collect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect)

And about form dispose, on Form close method it will automatically get disposed, but then if you have an variable for that form in some other form then it is advisable to write `form1 = null;` in `form1_disposed` event

Comment: can you please help me how can i work with GC ? because of knowing this fact that .NET Automatically moderates GC i have not been worked with GC ! thank you !

Comment: @Real2000: Although there are methods like GC.Collect(), you dont often require to implement it unless you have cases that your code ends abruptly or switches the threads. Things like Disposing the forms which are not required after closing and avoiding repetitive declarations of object will be helpful

Comment: I don't see what a GC.Collect would offer since the equivalent is running if the system is running low on memory. If that does not free enough bytes, a manual GC.collect call won't, too.

Comment: where should i write GC.Collect() ?! and i should add form.Dispose in form closed event ?

Comment: @Real2000: Please refer the Update 2