# Getting "A generic error occurred in GDI+" when saving image into a virtual folder on ASP.NET server

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gdi+

i have following coding to resize image and than save it my virtual folder "vicpic/scimages"

```
  if (FileUpload5.PostedFile != null)
    {
        if (FileUpload5.PostedFile.ContentLength > (1024 * 1024))
        {
            Label4.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 1 MB. Please resize your photo and than upload it again.";
        }
        else
        {
            System.Drawing.Image imageToBeResized = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload5.PostedFile.InputStream);
            int imageHeight = imageToBeResized.Height;
            int imageWidth = imageToBeResized.Width;
            int maxHeight = 660;
            int maxWidth = 560;
            imageHeight = (imageHeight * maxWidth) / imageWidth;
            imageWidth = maxWidth;
            if (imageHeight > maxHeight)
            {
                imageWidth = (imageWidth * maxHeight) / imageHeight;
                imageHeight = maxHeight;
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageToBeResized, imageWidth, imageHeight);
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            // bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Position = 0;
            byte[] image = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
            stream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);

            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload5.PostedFile.FileName);
            //Save files to disk
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload5.PostedFile.FileName);
            //Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/vicpic/scimages"), imageName);
            string imagename = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text + "4" + extension;


            bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/vicpic/scimages/") + imagename);

            bitmap.Dispose();
            imageToBeResized.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();



            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                Label4.Text = "Upload status:Successfully.";

            }
        }

    }
```

but it shows A generic error occurred in GDI+

can anyone suggest where the problem is?

i want to save image in "vicpic/scimages" folder on my host server. it is virtual directory and i also have granted all the permission required for the directory.

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: this "vicpic/scimages" is under httpdocs folder

Comment: May be you don't have permission to write/create a file.

Comment: no i have all the permission on the directory.

Comment: A generic error occurred in GDI+. it is my ERROR MESSAGE

Comment: Which line is causing the error ?

Comment: You should [avoid calling GC.Collect() yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1157350/588868)

Comment: @khyatipatel please trap the error in try/catch block and post the string .Message property of the error

Comment: Agree with @SteveB also try to replace explicit `Dispose` with `uses`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. It appears that the memory stream that the object was created on has to be open at the time the object is saved. Not to duplicate code and text just take a look at this Q & A: [A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

So instead of `bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/vicpic/scimages/") + imagename);` your code could look like this:

```
using (var m = new MemoryStream())
{
       bitmap.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       var img = Image.FromStream(m);
       img.Save(Server.MapPath("~/vicpic/scimages/") + imagename);
}
```

Comment: it shows error in this line:    var img = Image.FromStream(m);  below error:'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'

Comment: I see. You need to use another image class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream(v=vs.90).aspx Just add the `System.Drawing` namespace before `Image`.

Comment: i have following namespace in the code:                                             using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing;

Comment: Like this `var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(m);`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this is just my input that I want to give, if it can help someone with the same issue then that is all I want. I got this error in one of my websites and I had no idea what was going on so after finding some answers on STACK, I realised that it was a permission error. After fixing that everything was fine but then I got the same error on another website of mine and I immediately I changed the permission for the folder how ever this time it didn't fix it . After days of struggle I realised that the issue was just a misspelled folder name.