# Is there a way to check if garbage collection was triggered while analyzing dump file through SOS.dll

Tags: c#, debugging, garbage-collection, sos, sosex

I am analyzing a .dmp file for "OutofMemory" exception. The objects are staying in the memory for very long time, so is there a command to check if the garbage collection was triggered by using SOS.dll or SOSEX?

Comment: why not run memprofiler on the code?

Comment: You can start by looking at `!RootObjects` rather then triggered collections.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: okay, so how can this help me understand if there was a collection triggered?

Comment: 1 - What do you mean by "triggered"?  Like, ever?  Or do want to know if it is in the middle of a GC? 2 - Why do you want to know this? 3 - How do you know objects are staying in memory for a "long time"?

Comment: @SteveJohnson: When I look at the dump, I see a particular object staying in generation 2 almost occupying 500+ MB, so I wanted to check if the garbage collection ran or not.

Comment: @m_d_p29 If that's what you care about, then just check whether that object is rooted or not. If it's not, then you know there hasn't been a full GC since that object became unrooted.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you mention

> When I look at the dump, I see a particular object staying in generation 2 almost occupying 500+ MB, so I wanted to check if the garbage collection ran or not.

If you have an object in Gen 2, then garbage collection ran at least 2 times, otherwise it would be in Gen 0.

Now that you know it, it's obvious that this information is not really helpful. You want to know *why* it remains in memory.

To find out which reference keeps the large object in memory, use the SOS command `!gcroot`. When you know that, review your code to find out where such a reference comes from or where it should be removed.

If there is no reference any more, the object may be freed soon and it's just alive because no Gen 2 garbage collection has occurred since. See [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/4136325) on IDisposable, which discusses the point of releasing a large object.

In your case, it [might even be ok to call `GC.Collect()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157350/4136325) after releasing the reference. Usually you should not tamper with garbage collection, but if you always have such a large object and you certainly know that this object is no longer needed and `GC.Collect()` resolves the OOM exception, then it is the right thing to do.