# How to dispose object

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose, idisposable

How to dispose my object? I am doing it by this. Whats is wrong? The `Obj.Dispose()` function does not appear to be right.

```
class MainclassForm : Form, IDisposeable
{
    public void createanddispose()
    {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.dowork();
        obj.Dispose();//does not appear as a function
    }
}
```

Comment: IDisposeable, should not this be IDisposable. See this link as to how can you implement the interface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is type of `A`? In order for the object to be disposeable, it must implement IDisposable,

Comment: IDisposeable should be implemented by A class too ?

Comment: @qamar I already had gone through that example and what I could understand is in my question. Can u please give answer according to my code ?

Comment: @phpnet because the question is about obj.Dispose() does not appear as function... suppose A is `string` or `object` and obj is of type A. Then if you type obj.Dispose() - the method won't be shown there by intellisense (because there isn't any for non-disposable object)

Answer (score 2):

You can better use the `using` statement. Something like

```
using (MyIDisposableObject obj = new MyIDisposableObject())
{
    // object here
}
```

A good reference to check on MSDN: [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx)

> The C# "using" statement results in a call to Dispose(). This is the
>   same as Close(), which may throw exceptions when a network error
>   occurs. Because the call to Dispose() happens implicitly at the
>   closing brace of the "using" block, this source of exceptions is
>   likely to go unnoticed both by people writing the code and reading the
>   code. This represents a potential source of application errors.

Answer (score 1):

To call `Dispose()` on an object, your class must be inherited from `IDisposeable` interface and have an implementation of it:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
   public void Dispose()
   { 
      GC.Collect();           
   }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth [checking this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149197/gc-collect) before we throw `GC.Collect()` in too many places. It's a pretty specialized function, and probably not suitable for this use-case. It might be, I just wouldn't default to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here, but I believe the root is that you might confusing `IDisposable` with a [Garbage Collector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx).

`IDisposable` is an interface that the type `A`, in your example, may implement. It that were the case, you could be sure that any instance of `A` had the method `Dispose()` you're looking for. This is useful for things like `Stream`s, where they need to be closed, but it's not useful for (just as an example) a `ComplexNumber` type that has no outstanding resources.

In these cases, your *managed* C# code will handle all the "disposal" that needs to happen. It will get rid of the memory that object is using. That feature comes for free (sort of), and you don't need (or want) to do anything to explicitly invoke it. That's the main difference between managed (C#, Java, etc.) and unmanaged (C++) code.

Essentially, if an object is using more than just memory (like an open file does), `IDisposable` will be useful. If it is just memory (like a `Form`, or `DateTime`, or a majority of other things), there's no need for it.

As for your specific code, you've applied `IDisposable` to the type that contains *your* functions. Just as you couldn't call `this.AddMinutes(1)` to get at `DateTime`'s method, you can't get at this one.

If you do need the added functionality of implementing `IDisposable`, you'll have to do it on `A`. Applying `IDisposable`, like any other interface, to `MainclassForm` will tell the compiler that you have a `Dispose()` method on that class, which is true only because the Windows Forms object has one. If it didn't, this would throw a compiler error, and you'd have to add one.